# Weighted average of 2 tuples, each having 2 dictionaries (of dictionaries)

Tags: python, dictionary, hidden-markov-models

What would be the easiest/shortest/**most-Pythonic way to get the weighted average of `a` and `b`**?

```
a = (
        {
          0: {'P': 0.3, 'Z': 0.3, 'N': 0.3}, 
        'P': {'P': 0.9, 'Z': 0.1, 'N': 0.0}, 
        'Z': {'P': 0.1, 'Z': 0.9, 'N': 0.1}, 
        'N': {'P': 0.0, 'Z': 0.1, 'N': 0.9}
        },

        {
         'P': {'A': 0.3, 'C': 0.3, 'T': 0.2, 'G': 0.2}, 
         'Z': {'A': 0.3, 'C': 0.3, 'T': 0.2, 'G': 0.2}, 
         'N': {'A': 0.3, 'C': 0.3, 'T': 0.2, 'G': 0.2}
        }
    )

b = (
        {
          0: {'P': 0.3, 'Z': 0.3, 'N': 0.3}, 
        'P': {'P': 0.3, 'Z': 0.3, 'N': 0.3}, 
        'Z': {'P': 0.3, 'Z': 0.3, 'N': 0.3}, 
        'N': {'P': 0.3, 'Z': 0.3, 'N': 0.3}
        },

        {
         'P': {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'T': 0.25, 'G': 0.25}, 
         'Z': {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'T': 0.25, 'G': 0.25}, 
         'N': {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'T': 0.25, 'G': 0.25}
        }
    )
```

So that the resulting `c = [(a * a_weight) + (b * b_weight) / (a_weight + b_weight)]` should have the *same* structure (as `a` and `b`).

Should anyone know the Pythonic answer, thank you.

### Example of the resulting `c` structure

For instance, if `a_weight` = `b_weight` = 0.5 (a simple average), then `c`'s first `'P':` line

`'P': {'P': (0.9 + 0.3) / 2, 'Z': (0.1 + 0.3) / 2, 'N': (0.0 + 0.3) / 2}`

would be an average of

`a`'s `'P': {'P': 0.9, 'Z': 0.1, 'N': 0.0}` and
`b`'s `'P': {'P': 0.3, 'Z': 0.3, 'N': 0.3}`.

Basically, just an average of `value`s (while every `key` stays as is).

Comment: What is **your** (although not the easiest/shortest/most-Pythonic, but still your) proposal?

Comment: It's not Pythonic (at all). I'd manually go through both elements of the tuple (ie. dictionaries of dictionaries) ... use plenty of helper variables ... and put it all back together.  

Basically, I'd just hack my way through with a help from IDLE and [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) ... which isn't much of a solution.

Comment: What would be the contents of the resulting C?

Comment: @courteous, which is the weight and which is the value in the above structure? Also Please give an example of how you would arrive to `c`

Comment: @Abhijit I've updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a function that accepts two inputs and converts them recursively according to their type:

```
def combine(a, b, a_weight, b_weight):
    if isinstance(a, tuple):
        return tuple(combine(x,y,a_weight,b_weight) for x,y in zip(a,b))
    elif isinstance(a, dict):
        return dict((k, combine(a[k],b[k],a_weight,b_weight)) for k in a)
    #add other data structures here if you need to (e.g. list, set, etc.)
    else: #assume a number
        return ((a * a_weight) + (b * b_weight)) / (a_weight + b_weight)
```

The nice thing about this method is that it will keep working even if you change the structure of the inputs.

Note that this code assumes that the structure of `a` and `b` is the same, the tuples have the same number of elements, and the dictionaries have the same keys. If this is not always the case you'd need to add code to verify this.

Comment: It will not work properly if for example some part of b has a key that is not present in a. No idea if the OP has this case thou. Apart from that it will work properly.

Comment: This is _so_ neat. And generalizable as well. I'd never come up with that. Thank you!

Comment: There should be another brace around the last `return`, right? Either way, it only works for a _simple_ average (both `weight`s being 0.5) ... and I can't find out why.  

I've also added `print` statement before each `return` ... is the order of `print` guaranteed to be in-order?

Comment: @courteous: Yes, there should have been another brace which I added now (I had copied that part from your question). The order of `print` output will be the same order they were executed.

Comment: @interjay That is fine, but your function (apparently) still only works on simple averages (with weights = 0.5). :)

Comment: I really don't know why this is so ... but (as in my updated post), when I `combine` `m1` with itself, I should get the same numbers out (regardless of `weight`s), right?

Comment: @courteous: I tested it and I get `m1 == m2`

Comment: Which weights (`a_weight` and `b_weight`) did you use?  
  
For example, using `a_weight = 1` and `b_weight = 100`, I get `m2` full of 0.6633... values.

Comment: @courteous: It looks like you aren't using the fixed version of the parentheses then. That works for me.

Comment: I do, I do! I get such results, running (only) your code in Python shell. I'll update my question ... really want to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @courteous: You are not running the same code. Copy my code exactly and it will work.

Comment: Outrageous mistake. :) I'll clean up this part of the question.